# Or-ing return values for the same function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a nicer way of doing this in python?:

```
((w.endswith('<') or w.endswith('</'))
```

perhaps `any` can be used

Comment: @tynn No I beg to differ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `endswith` method on strings can take a tuple as an argument:

```
w.endswith(('<','<\'))
```